# Unable to load 'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI" for DataConnectionDialog use

Tags: c#, .net, api, database-connection, sqlconnection

I created an application in C# , .Net 4.0.
In this application i need to show a DataConnectionDialog for accessing DataBase.

**I use this code :**

```
 DataConnectionDialog BDdialog = new DataConnectionDialog();
 DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(BDdialog);
 BDdialog.SelectedDataSource = DataSource.OdbcDataSource;
 BDdialog.SelectedDataProvider = DataProvider.OdbcDataProvider;
 DataConnectionDialog.Show(BDdialog);
```

On my laptop, the code works fine, but on another laptot, with .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 there is an Exception when i try to open this Dialog :

[image]

Nevertheless, i added these DLL in the same directory of my exe :

```
Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog.dll
Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog.resources.dll
Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll
```

Anyone could help me ? How correcting this error please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get these libraries files from Nuget source.

https://nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/1.2

Comment: Wow, so fast ! Your answer is the good ! I use Nuget and all is ok now ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that this package is no longer available. I'm trying to figure out how to use the new one but it's not clear as all I see are 2 interfaces and nothing else. The odd thing is that Microsoft refers to 'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI' in their own documentation which odd and yet they don't seem to be providing it.

Comment: @Thierry Did you find a way to use the DataConnectionDialog?

Comment: @PhilJollans I did... I ended keeping the old reference and libraries! Shame that this is not updated but in all fairness the one I'm using does the trick.