# Missing Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI library

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to build a `WinForm` app in which I can create custom connection strings using the `ConnectionUI` dialog from Windows. But I cannot find anywhere this DLLs:

```
Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI
```

Where can I find it?

Comment: You can use NuGet source to get the dll, as proposed in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469960/unable-to-load-microsoft-data-connectionui-for-dataconnectiondialog-use

Comment: It looks like that's a part of the [Data Designer Extensibility (DDE) SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165128(v=vs.90).aspx). You might try searching for that.