# Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I try to convert a VS 2015 C# project to the new VS 2017 
but I can't find a way to use the old
Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog

I try downloading NuGet Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI but still not working, the DataConnetionDialog is still missing

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks
Paolo

Answer (score 2):

The DataConnectionDialog is a separate package:

https://nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/1.2

This was already answered here:

[Unable to load 'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI" for DataConnectionDialog use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469960/unable-to-load-microsoft-data-connectionui-for-dataconnectiondialog-use)

However, it is has been "unlisted", which means you won't find it in "Manage Packages for Solution" window. You can install it via the "Package Manager Console" with the command:

```
Install-Package DataConnectionDialog -Version 1.2.0
```

**Edit**

and based on this answer:

[Is there a free "Add Connection" or "SQL Connection" Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567981/is-there-a-free-add-connection-or-sql-connection-dialog)

Microsoft had published the source for the Visual Studio connection dialog. That is also no longer available, but there is a copy of it here:

https://github.com/kjbartel/ConnectionDialog